# Ordering with creating and reading a file in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I know it is something with the catalog that is the issue, I just can't figure out how to work around it.

I have the following code and I get the following error:

```
class test1 {
  file { '/tmp/test.txt':
    ensure  => present,
    content => 'name=joe',
  }
}

class test2 {
  $test = file('/tmp/test.txt')
  notify { $test: }
}

class test3 {
  class { 'test1': } ->
  class { 'test2': }
}

puppet apply -e "include test3"

Error: Could not find any files from test.txt at ../modules/test2/manifests/init.pp
```

So essentially, I am trying to read a file before it exists, and the ordering doesn't appear to be working. Any ideas how I can work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of the function you are trying to utilize it will never operate in the fashion you are trying.

> [file:](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#file) 
>   Loads a file from a module and returns its contents as a string.

Affectively what this means is that the file would exist in

> test1/files/test.txt

And would be loaded using:
`file('test1/test.txt')` i.e. `file(<MODULENAME>/<FILENAME>)`

Comment: I should have pointed out that the file is being loaded into the "file" function by its absolute path: i.e. file('/tmp/test.txt')